# Is there a way to quickly find hidden processes in the Windows OS?

Tags: c, windows

I want to know how to quickly find hidden processes in the Windows OS.

How to find hidden processes that are currently in use.

1. Find the PID in multiples of 4 using the BroutForce method.
2. Compare with the list found with CreateToolHelp32Snapshot API.

Is there a way to find it faster than the current use?

Comment: Use [`EnumProcesses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses)?

Comment: @alk EnumProcesses uses the same list as the toolhelp API

Comment: So is your question about speed or completeness?

Comment: @alk  Yes, it's a faster way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rootkit hidden process will probably use a driver and unhook itself from the list of processes. I doubt `OpenProcess` will work even if you know the pid. Fighting a kernel-rootkit from usermode is nearly impossible.

Comment: Hello anders.

I agree with you.

I do not think the above method is always right.

However, I have used SSDT hooking to find hidden processes.

So I'm looking for a better way (Fast).


Thank you for your valuable feedback.